# htaccess RewriteRule My code is working properly but i want to make it dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dynamic

My code is working properly but i want to make it dynamic. 
My code is:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^version=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /cms_name/abc/abc_%1/ [R=301,L] [R=301]
    RewriteRule (.*) /cms_name/abc/abc/ [R=301,L]
```

[In simple words, my code redirects **/cms_name/abc** (entered in URL bar) to **/cms_name/abc_50** ]

Now this "cms_name" is going to change depending upon what user types in URL bar of browser(say for ex. */drupal/abc/* or */wordpress/abc/* ect).
When i hardcode this value in htaccess file then it works fine for that particular "cms_name" only.

**How to make it works properly depending on what "cms_name" user types in url bar of browser.**

[How to get the entire URL(using RewriteCond may be) in htaccess file ]

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong at multiple places.

To answer what you're asking you can do:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^version=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1/abc/abc_%1/ [R=301,L]
```